# Orthodox Visits to Other Denomination Sanctuaries

Tags: orthodox, synagogue, heterodox

Why is it that some people won't set foot in another's sanctuary, even if it was for a non-prayer function?  Can an orthodox person be in a reform style temple sanctuary for a lecture or concert? I understand possible discomfort with prayer services but sanctuaries are often used for other purposes.

Comment: Hi, joeyb! Welcome to mi.yodeya!
Thanks for jumping right in with such an excellent and power-packed question. I wouldn't be surprised if it takes some time and maybe iterations before there's a complete answer. If you feel the need to respond to any of the answers, I recommend leaving a comment on the answer.
Please consider registering your account so that you'll have access to all of mi.yodeya's features. To do this, click on register or login at the top of the page, click on the icon for a service you use (eg GMail), and follow the prompts.

Comment: It appears to me that there is no problem in a place that doesn't worship avodah zarah

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/281/attending-non-frum-event

Comment: I have the same question regarding a Kaplan Course for SAT given in a temple

Comment: @regina Check out our other question on that topic specifically: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31977/759

Answer (score 14):

Rav Moshe in his [Igros Moshe EH 2:17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=330&hilite=) second paragraph he seems to make it clear that for davening it is for sure assur, and even when it is a wedding an Orthodox person should not go. This tshuva was regarding Conservative synagogues; I am guessing that all the more so this would apply to Reform.

Comment: R. Feinstein is likely referring to a wedding that is being officiated by a Conservative rabbi.

Comment: read the teshuva

Comment: Davening and weddings are religious functions; what does he say about things like lectures and concerts?

Comment: @monicacellio , he writes that from the strict letter of the law its not a prohibition during non prayer times since there is no chosed that a person is praying there. Regarding a speech and concert it is not held during prayers so one wouldnt think the person is there to pray.

Answer (score 6):

I believe [R' Moshe Feinstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe%5FFeinstein) has a responsum regarding an Orthodox rabbi performing a wedding at a heterodox synagogue, in which he says "your job as rabbi is to perform weddings, regardless of location", but I don't recall if he addresses the sanctuary-vs-social-hall aspect.  Hopefully I'll find it later?

Comment: See http://haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=862&cat=9&haoro=3, http://haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=866&cat=9&haoro=5, http://haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=867&cat=9&haoro=3, 
and http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=868&cat=9&haoro=5 for various points/counterpoints on this, including a discussion of R' Moshe's various teshuvos relating to this issue.

Comment: I don't have a source available, but this is what I have seen in practice:  in smaller Orthodox communities, where Orthodox synagogues don't have ample space to host events (Bar/Bat mitzvah, wedding, etc.) they will often rent the social hall of a large Reform or Conservative synagogue.  HOWEVER - they will never enter the sanctuary, for any reason.  I have seen a chuppah set up in the lobby, with guests packed in tightly, while on the other side of the double doors, a large empty sanctuary room sat unused.  (The reception was in the social hall).

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99/orthodox-visits-to-other-denomination-sanctuaries#comment42245_17936

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a citation (if somebody else does maybe they could edit it in, otherwise I'll keep looking) but R' Moshe Feinstein z'l rules that kefira (heresy) is the same as avoda zara (idol worship) with regards to the halachos of entering a place of worship, and that since reform and conservative reject many if not most of the Rambam's 13 ikarim (principals of faith), they are places of kefira and the actual sanctuary may not be entered.

Aside from this there is the issue of maris ayin (giving the appearance of wrongdoing).  Even if there were not a specific law prohibiting entering the sanctuary, reform and conservative are not halachically legitimate movements and entering them as a religious Jew might give the false impression that their breaks with Torah are acceptable.

Comment: Could you clarify your second paragraph?  Is that R. Feinstein's opinion, or yours?

Comment: @MonicaCellio it is also R' Feinstein.

Comment: You could improve this answer by citing and optionally translating important quotations from the particular responsum you're referring to.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I would love to find where in Igros it is so I can do so.

Answer (score 3):

R' Moshe Feinstein z'l is no longer with us. This is an excellent question to demonstrate the dictum that you should have your questions answered by your Rabbi, not by a book. Of course, your rabbi will know of R' Feinstein's rulings, but he will also know of your circumstances, the reason for the proposed visit, etc.

A friend of mine, a black-hat from Monsey NY, was recently told by his Rabbi that it was permissible to attend the Shabbat Shareit bat-mitzvah (in a conservative synagogue) of my friend's niece (his brother's daughter). The Rabbi cited issues of peace within the family and not insulting my friend's brother as reasons to trump (in this particular case) the reasons for not attending.

Comment: Who was suggesting that someone should ever rule by a book instead of their rabbi?

Comment: Ummm that's the implication of the other answers to this question.

Comment: Ummmm no it's not.