# Is it permitted to attend a non-Jewish wedding?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, wedding

Is it permitted to attend a non-Jewish wedding? Assume for the purpose of this question that the wedding is occuring in a non-religious location (such as a hotel). If it is permitted to attend, is it permitted to participate in such a wedding (such as by reading a non-religious poem).

Is there a difference between (for example) a Christian wedding, a Muslim wedding, and a non-religious wedding?

Related:

[Attending a relative's non-Jewish wedding in a non-Jewish place of worship?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22978/1713)

[Attending non-frum event](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/281/1713)

[Intermarriage Attendance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12713/1713)