# Rules for non-kosher kitchen

Tags: kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul

What are the rules for cooking in a non-kosher kitchen with kosher utensils (pots, cutlery, etc).

- Can a microwave be used  if its contents are double-wrapped?
- Can the burners on a non-kosher oven be used?
- Can  dishes be washed in a non-kosher sink?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing to depersonalise the question. Feel free to further edit yourself.

Comment: You really should ask a rabbi, though. It's generally not a good idea to base real-life practice of halacha on the advice of random people on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer from summarizing this [OU article](https://oukosher.org/blog/industrial-kosher/mission-not-impossible-the-kosher-jew-in-a-non-kosher-milieu/):

In both a conventional and microwave oven, double covering the food in foil or plastic is sufficient. (The article explains what the concern is.) A covered hard plastic container is, itself already one layer, so all you need is to cover that in a layer of plastic wrap or foil. An aluminum pan covered with a sheet of foil is all one layer. Then cover that in another layer of foil.

Regarding the stove burners, I am citing an excerpt from another [Mi Yodeya answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40789/5275)

> After the Return by Rabbis Mordechai Becher and Moshe Newman, a
>   guidebook for baalei t'shuva, covers this
>
> You can cook on a non-kosher stove so long as the burner ring is clean
>   (he doesn't cite a source).