# Going into Reform Synagogues

Tags: halacha, synagogue, heterodox, orthodox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Orthodox Visits to Other Denomination Sanctuaries](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99/orthodox-visits-to-other-denomination-sanctuaries)

I have noticed that in the two years that I have spent in the Jewish community, that Orthodox Jews say that they would never step foot into a Reform Synagogue, what is the reasoning behind this? Is there any hallacha that states that you shouldn't go into an Reform synagogue?

Note: My title is a bit weak, if anyone has any ideas of another title, please comment it.